# Selenium python code quits the webpage after execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Selenium code quits the webpage page after executing, although I added the line "driver.quit()" and it quits after loading the webpage.

Note: The browser is Microsoft Edge

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    driver = webdriver.Edge()
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/?app")
    driver.set_window_size(1285, 824)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **driver.quit()** method is used to close the entire browser session, and it should be used at the end of your script when you are done with the browser.

Try like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/?app")
driver.set_window_size(1285, 824)

# Add some interactions or operations on the page
# For example, click a button or wait for a few seconds
time.sleep(5)
```